# Randomly select rows of a matrix with weights in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Say I want to randomly select 3 rows from matrix `m`

```
m = [1 2 1; 1 1 1; 1 1 1; 2 1 1; 2 2 1; 1 1 1; 1 1 1; 2 1 1];
sample = m(randsample(1:length(m),3),:)
```

However, I want to randomly select rows with weights. So I need a vector that corresponds to each row of `m`. I want to apply a weighting to each row depending on the number (or ratio) of `1` and `2` that are present in each row.

Perhaps something like this?

```
w1 = 0.6;                 %weight of 1
w2 = 0.4;                 %weight of 2
w = m;
w(w == 1) = w1;
w(w == 2) = w2;
w = (sum(w,2))*0.1        %vector of weights
```

But this is wrong:

```
sample = m(randsample(1:length(m),2),:,true,w)
```

Please help.

Comment: Presumably it's because your syntax is wrong, and you need `m(randsample(1:length(m),2,true,w),:)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Staying with your code, I think you were needed to normalize the weights and then select rows based on the random samples calculated from `randsample` using the normalized weights.
So, the following changes are needed for your code -

```
w = sum(w,2)./sum(sum(w,2)) %// Normalize weights
sample = m(randsample([1:size(m,1)], 3, true, w) ,:)
```

---

Or if I can start-over and want to make the code concise, I could do like so -

```
%// Inputs
m = [1 2 1; 1 1 1; 1 1 1; 2 1 1; 2 2 1; 1 1 1; 1 1 1; 2 1 1]
w1 = 0.6;                 %// weight of 1
w2 = 0.4;                 %// weight of 2

%// Scale each row of w according to the weights assigned for 1 and 2.
%// Thus, we will have weights for each row
sum_12wts = sum(w1.*(m==1),2) + sum(w2.*(m==2),2)

%// Normalize the weights, so that they add upto 1, as needed for use with
%// randsample
norm_weights = sum_12wts./sum(sum_12wts)

%// Get 3 random row indices from m using randsample based on normalized weights
row_ind = randsample([1:size(m,1)], 3, true, norm_weights) 

%// Index into m to get the desired output
out = m(row_ind,:)
```